# No Internet Access after setting the static IP address on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ip-address, static-ip, control-panel

I had set the static IP address from control panel then checked "validate settings upon exit" and hit close then no internet access to the Wi-Fi shown. Meanwhile a windows network diagnostic starts and after some time it shows some issues

1. DHCP is not enabled for "Wi-Fi" (not fixed)

- Automatically update your network settings (failed)

2. Problem with wireless adapter or access point (not fixed)

- Investigate router or access point issues (failed)
- Reset the wireless adapter (completed)

Comment: Default route? DNS servers? Static IP address in same subnet as router?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why did you do this? What were you trying to actually achieve? Once you reverted to DHCP did the problem disappear? If so, then next time, use the gateway to fix static IP addresses, not the client.

Comment: i tried again by interchanging the prefered and alternate dns address it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay.. I am setting the static address using control panel
I had put the IP Address, Subnet Mask and Default Gateway by entering `ipcongig/all` in Command Prompt (Administrator).
Firstly I was putting first address in preferred and second in alternate that gives me no internet access
Now I had interchanged the DNS addresses got from `ipconfig/all`.
And I had put first address in alternate and second address in preferred.
This one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have come across a very unintuitive "feature" of Windows...

Instead of warning you about a duplicate ip address when you enter one manually, ***Windows silently gives you a special private ip address*** which cannot be routed in the range 169.254.0.0 to 169.254.255.255 (So-called Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA)).

There are 2 locations where one can set the ip address. Click the properties link in the wifi connection to get to the first one.

[image]

Then scroll down to the ***Edit*** button:

[image]

Select ***Manual*** in the top dropdown box and enter an address:

[image]

This is defines an ip address for the network connection.
If that address is already in use on your network, you'll see the following in when running `ipconfig /all`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-F3-9A-0A-44-CA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.99.219(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.101.199(Duplicate)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.101.1
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

As can be seen, Autoconfiguration inserts a private ip address before the manually set ip address.
The (Duplicate) behind the manually set address is the only indication that your address is in use.

The other place where you can set a manual address is on the nic properties.

[image]

Here you can set more than one address, if for some reason you need to.

[image]

[image]

If you want another address, select **Advanced** and add it.

[image]

Now, `ipconfig /all` will show what you specified.

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-F3-9A-0A-44-CA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.88.99(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.101.99(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.101.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.101.1
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Finally, profit!

Comment: thanks for the answer... as you see i fixed it at that time... sorry to say but now i dont believe that i had asked this stupid question about two years back... thanks for the effort...